# how to reference ng-template from ng-container with if expression

Tags: angular

I have this template I want to reference in 2 different `ng-template` sections:

```html
<ng-template #expandedRow>
  <tr>
    <td>Some content</td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

I am referencing it like this:

```html
<ng-template #folderContent>
  <ng-container *ngIf="expanded; then expandedRow else undefined"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

Is there a better way of doing using `if` `then`.

Is there a way to use `[hidden]` like this as it is not supported on `ng-container`.

Comment: What about handling whether ng-template should be visible inside the template itself instead? Would it be feasible? Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-xs4oge?file=app/app.component.html (making use of `ngTemplateOutlet` instead)

Comment: would absolutely love to know why this was voted down

Comment: no idea either, this doesn't sound as a bad question at all, to me. Perhaps slightly off topic, but still, it's full of questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is feasible in your case, but you may determine whether the template is visible in the **template itself** making use of `ngTemplateOutlet`:

I would approach it in this way:

```html
<ng-template #folderContent>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="expandedRow; context: { visible: expanded }"></ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

And, in the expandedRow template:

```html
<ng-template #expandedRow let-contentVisible="visible">
  <tr *ngIf="contentVisible">
    <td>Some content</td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

This allows you to pass additional contextual parameters to the template itself, allowing to determine whether the template is visible directly inside the template itself.

Working stackblitz example to play around with it can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-xs4oge?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can try with reverse order as like below.

```
<ng-contaniner *ngIf="true else newone">
<div> true works</div> 
</ng-container>
    <ng-template #newone>
    false works</ng-template>
```